# TGAccessoryManager causes argument exception on fireDataReceived

Tags: iphone, ios

I've been trying to research this error for a while, but to no avail.  Every time it looks like TGAccessoryManager should be sending my application data, an argument exception occurs:

```
  2013-04-30 11:46:01.905 mindyieldapp[14537:907] Exception: *** -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary
  2013-04-30 11:46:01.918 mindyieldapp[14537:907] Stack trace: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x33d7f2bb <redacted> + 186
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3ba2497f objc_exception_throw + 30
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x33d0bff5 <redacted> + 212
        3   mindyieldapp                        0x000c1539 -[TGAccessoryManager fireDataReceived:] + 336
```

I'm certain my code is wired up correctly, as I've stripped it down significantly, and the accessoryDidConnect/accessoryDidDisconnect selectors are being called.  I'm targeting iOS 6.1, with the latest version of the Neurosky SDK (I just re-downloaded to be sure).  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear, copyItems is not an instance of NSDicitonary. Put a breakpoint on
the line with [NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] and see of what type is copyItems instance of.